# Okular and Fileopen plug-in

Tags: plugins, okular

Someone knows how to install FileOpen plug-in for read a secure PDF file  with Okular, on Ubuntu 16.04?   I've bought a DIN standard but to read it we need FileOpen plug-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if Okular has support for this plugin as it is written for Adobe reader. I was able to download the old [Adobe Reader 8](ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/unix/) for linux and install the plugin from the [FileOpen site](http://plugin.fileopen.com/). To get the plugin working just untar the archive and copy the FileOpen.AR8.api file to the Adobe Reader 8 plugins folder normally: `/opt/Adobe/Reader8/Reader/intellinux/plug_ins/`